Need to update table from another row in same table
I have data in one table as below:



Account_Id
Month
Source
Code




12345
31/03/2023
New
abc6789


12345
31/03/2023
Old
abc1234



I like the data to be as below in teradata using sql.
can anyone plz help



Account_Id
Month
Source
Code




12345
31/03/2023
New
abc6789


12345
31/03/2023
Old
abc6789



I am expecting the data as explained above

Provide table structure and more details

Let your table name is Data
UPDATE A
FROM  DATA A, DATA B 
SET CODE = B.CODE
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.ACCOUNT_ID
AND  A.SOURCE ='OLD'
AND B.SOURCE ='NEW'
AND A.MONTH = B.MONTH

